# Could bimonthly be semimonthly? How many times a month does "bimonthly" really mean?

Tags: word-meaning

For me, the word "***bimonthly***" has always been confusing whether it means twice a month or once every two months. Looking up the word in some dictionaries today, I noticed that all the dictionaries I checked it up define the word as something like "*every two months **OR** twice a month*". Below are some examples.

> Collins Dictionary  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/ 
> 1. every
> two months
> 2. (often avoided because of confusion with sense 1) twice a month; semimonthly

> Merriam-Webster  https://www.merriam-webster.com/ 
> 1. occurring
> every two months
> 2. occurring twice a month : semimonthly

> Oxford Learner's Dictionaries   https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/ 
> produced or happening every two months or twice each month

> Longman Dictionary    https://www.ldoceonline.com/  
> appearing or
> happening every two months or twice each month

Since the "*every two months*" definition always comes first in all those dictionaries, I assume that it is the commonly-understood meaning by native speakers in general, but how can you be so certain that it really means every two months?

Comment: If the dictionaries can't agree on a definition, then what chance do we stand?

Comment: I personally never use any of the *bi-[**time period**]* words, simply because they are so ambiguous. If I mean twice a month, I say twice a month; if I mean every other month, I say every other month. There is no reason to use a single word that's ambiguous over three words that are completely unambiguous.

Comment: I agree with Jason. The problem is how to interpret the word when it is written. Can I just assume that in nine out of ten cases it means every two months?

Comment: @Takashi   its probably more like 60/40 in favour of 'every two <whatever>'

Comment: @Mike: Thanks. I guess it may be more like 90/10 in case the word is used in publishing industry, so a bi-monthly magazine would most probably be published every other month(?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bi-Monthly (once every two months)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284367/bi-monthly-once-every-two-months)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those definitions are correct, bi-monthly  (or indeed bi-weekly, bi-yearly etc.) is ambiguous. The fact that it is still commonly used is basically inexplicable. Sorry!